# svelte component not rerender conditionals in child component with data of parent component with {#each} loop

Tags: javascript, html, frameworks, reactive-programming, svelte

the complete code is here:
https://svelte.dev/repl/a2af19fc79e246f9956968db9c2f5aa6?version=3.50.1

basically, at the first click, everything works fine

but when you click the second time everything is broken.

---

✅ WHEN WORK FINE:

[image]

❌ WHEN DON'T WORK:

### [image]

I am trying to see where is the bug for 2 days now,

and I found that if I try to `console.log()` my conditionals the first time it will console, but the second time not.

---

the data is got from the parent to the child.

and the data is an array, and we loop on it and for each item, we create a child.

so changing the array in the parent should trigger rerender also in the child.

---

at some point this was a lot of debugging for me, so I tried to convert all my variables to `$:`

and still don't work.

but technically should work also with `const` since we recreate a new line from scratch (`@each`)

---

from what I see the data is passed correctly and also console.log every time.

but conditionals like `sameY = y === prevY;`

don't get rerender when `y` or `prevY` get rerendered

---

here where the values should be correct (inside `Gline.svelte`)

```html
<div
  class="h-px bg-cyan-500 absolute origin-bottom-left"
  style="width:{setLineWidth()}px; transform:translate({prevX}px, {prevY}px) rotate({setLineAngle()}deg);"
  transition:scale
/>
```

you see there is `setLineWidth()`, `{prevX}`, `{prevY}` variables that need to change.

and technically first time change correctly but other times don't do it.

---

I am asking if someone can know why and show me I can fix it.

I am open to suggestions if you want

Comment: Please include *all relevant* code in the question itself.

Comment: (If that is a lot of code, reduce it down to a minimal reproducible example. I.e. the smallest amount of code exhibiting the problem. You should do that in general, as it helps identify the issue.)

Comment: For rendering diagrams I would recommend using SVGs rather than HTML elements, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For performance reasons, the `#each` by default does **not** fully recreate everything, instead it adds or removes items at the end. To circumvent this, a key can be provided in parentheses at the end.

The key has to uniquely identify the object; usually something like a number or string is used so unchanged items do not have to be recreated (e.g. if an item is inserted in the middle, all other items remain the same).

Here you can just specify the whole item, as the reference will change, so it will update everything correctly:

```html
{#each coordsArray as thisCoords, index (thisCoords)}
```

[Docs for `#each`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-each)

Comment: bro, is fantastic, really it works!!!!!! I am not gonna lie but it works even with const vars!